# How to set the docker user in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

The following is my yml file for Github Actions. I want to set the user of the docker to root for the following via the docker options (`--user root`) . How can I do this via Github Actions?

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: run zap
      uses: docker://sshniro/zap_action
      with:
        args: zap-baseline.py -t https://www.example.com
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think you can pass docker container arguments when using `uses:`, but you can set them with job containers.

Try this workflow:

```
name: ZAP
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: owasp/zap2docker-stable
      options: --user root
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: run zap
        run: zap-baseline.py -t https://www.example.com
```

You can find the documentation for the `job.<job_id>.container` syntax [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer).

Comment: This is not the same. It will run all steps in the docker container. This will break badly if you use e.g. Alpine, in which case you need the 'uses: docker://alpine' syntax. And that syntax is underdocumented as to how to pass additional arguments to docker.